# ordenar un arreglo pero se duplican los datos

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, array

Que tal este es mi primer post, tengo un problema a la hora de querer ordenar un array que voy a mostrar

tengo dos arrays "ordenablearray" que contiene el array ordenado con el numero de estrellas ya sea mayor a menor o menor a mayor

el segundo contiene la informacion de hoteles de donde saco la informacion de las estrellas (este no esta ordenado ni nada, tal cual como lo recibi asi esta)

la variable "orderby_" contiene el texto "estrellas"

este es mi codigo:

```
$.each(ordenablearray, function (camp) {

    $.each(hoteles, function (campo) {

        var ant = parseInt(camp) - 1;

        if (hoteles[campo] != null) {

            if (orderby_ != "nombre") {

                var datatoorder = hoteles[campo]['estrellas'];

                if (datatoorder == ordenablearray[camp] && JSON.stringify(hoteles[campo]) != JSON.stringify(nuevo[ant])) {
                    nuevo[camp] = filtrodatos.hoteles[campo];
                }
            } 
        }
    });
    if (orderby_ == "nombre") {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Ejemplo de el array hoteles

```
hoteles = {
  0 {
     nombre: hotel prueba,
     estrellas: 4,
     numberId: 3385
      },
  1: {
     nombre: hotel prueba2,
     estrellas: 4,
     numberId: 3386,
      },
 2: {
     nombre: hotel prueba3,
     estrellas: 5,
     numberId: 3387
      },
3: {
     nombre: hotel prueba4,
     estrellas: 4,
     numberId: 3388,
      },
4: {
     nombre: hotel prueba5,
     estrellas: 5,
     numberId: 3389
      },
5: {
     nombre: hotel prueba6,
     estrellas: 4,
     numberId: 3390
      }
}
```

el problema es que cuando hay mas de 2 hoteles con 4 estrellas solo guarda los primeros 2 y luego los repite hasta que encuentra uno de menor estrellas

Answer (score 0):

Para ordenar arreglos puedes utilizar el método [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort). El método sort te permite agregar una función como parámetro de este método para ingresar las condiciones que necesites para ordenar tus datos.

En el ejemplo a continuación coloque para ordenar de mayor a menor y esta comentado para ordenar de menor a mayor.

```js
hoteles = [
   {
     nombre: 'hotel prueba 1',
     estrellas: 4,
     numberId: 3385
      },
   {
     nombre: 'hotel prueba 2',
     estrellas: 4,
     numberId: 3386,
      },
  {
     nombre: 'hotel prueba 3',
     estrellas: 5,
     numberId: 3387
      },
 {
     nombre: 'hotel prueba 4',
     estrellas: 4,
     numberId: 3388,
      },
 {
     nombre: 'hotel prueba 5',
     estrellas: 5,
     numberId: 3389
      },
{
     nombre: 'hotel prueba 6',
     estrellas: 4,
     numberId: 3390
      }
];

hoteles.sort(function(a, b) {
    //return a.estrellas - b.estrellas; // De menor a mayor
    return b.estrellas - a.estrellas; // De mayor a menor
});

console.log(hoteles);
```